# 18:04 System getting slow

Tags: updates, performance, bug-reporting

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 in my new [Lenovo V130](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/in/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-v-series-laptops/v130-14igm/documentation) laptop, since beginning I am finding some kind of lag in the OS. As I am regular user of Ubuntu, I noticed this lag in my new laptop. 
Is there any kind of bug or some another problem ?
Please help...

Comment: What processor are you using?

Comment: It also happens to me. My gvim is getting really slow. I thought it was the problem of gvim. Turns out evolution is also becoming slow.

Comment: There are multiple versions of the V130 with different CPUs and drives. Which do you have? Please find the serial number then go to https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/in/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-v-series-laptops/v130-14igm and enter it there to find your specific model type.

Comment: @Itakura : The configuration is Intel Core i3-7020,2.30 GHz,Lenovo V130,8GB,1TB,14 Screen

Comment: @K7AAY : The configuration is Intel Core i3-7020,2.30 GHz,Lenovo V130,8GB,1TB,14 Screen

Comment: What programs were you running when logged in ubuntu when you experienced these lags? You can type in terminal `ps -aux` to look at all processes being run.